# Android Activity- Client to Server Connection with onResume method

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-button, android-lifecycle

```
 package studio_codec.reportingsystem;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
 import android.net.NetworkInfo;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.Toast;


 import javax.xml.datatype.Duration;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
public EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
public String Username = username.getText().toString();
public String Password = password.getText().toString();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}

protected void onStart() {

    if (!internet_check()) {

        Context context = getApplication();
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        CharSequence Error_connection_message = "Please Connect with Internet.Turn on Mobile Data Service";
        Toast Error_Connection = Toast.makeText(context, Error_connection_message, duration);
        Error_Connection.show();;
    }
}


protected void onResume() {

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View button) {

            if (Username == null && (Password.equals(""))) {
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "Please Check your Login Credentials! ";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast Error_credentials = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                Error_credentials.show();


            }

            else{

                // here ..use a function to parse json data and connect to server
            }

        }
    });


}

public boolean internet_check() {
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
   }
   }
```

I have just read the Android Activity Life Cycle and i would like to know the code i wrote will work as i planned. I need the code to display an XML file when user clicks on my app and once its in the onStart method i need to know if the device is connected to a network and when onResume starts i need ,if the user click on button , i need to check if the fields are empty. Here i have only two text fields .One for username and another one for password.
thank you.

Comment: Did you try to run this? Was there any error/non-required behavior?

Comment: no..but it did not show any errors in my android studio.i have just one doubt.when it executes  onResume method, does it show my login layout xml file?  @Presak Sola   . can u help me

Comment: It will show `activity_main.xml` file. Is that your login layout file?

Comment: yes it is. i have a problem running this application. that's the reason i am here. my emulator takes too much time to run. i have a system with 2 GB ram and core2 Duo processor.

Comment: Try gennymotion. Its a bit fast (not much though).